# query result not return value in row

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables join to show the count value of first table and i write a query like this

i have a table that contain category called [PEBPC] that contain a 3 producer category

> USE [P1OTP]
>
> ```
>  SELECT pe.[ID] AS [No]
>         ,pe.[NAME] AS [ProducerType]
>            ,coalesce(COUNT(CASE tp.[NewProducer] WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [NewProducers]
>            ,coalesce(COUNT(CASE tp.[NewProducer] WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [ExistProducer]
>            ,coalesce(COUNT(tp.[NewProducer]),0) AS [Total]
>   FROM [TPDCS] 
>  LEFT  JOIN [PEBPC] pe ON pe.[ID] = tp.[estbProducerID]
>  WHERE 1 = 1
>      AND tp.[OrganizationAddrProvince] IS NOT NULL
>      AND tp.[OrganizationAddrProvince] = '81'
>      AND tp.[libDocumentID] IN(SELECT [ParentID] FROM [TPDTS] WHERE [CategoryID] IS NOT NULL) >
>      GROUP BY pe.[ID] 
>         ,pe.[NAME]   ORDER BY pe.[ID]
> ```

when this query run it's only show just 2 category because this province have just 1 and 2 category

```
    No  Type of Producer    NewProducer   ExistProducer    Total

    1   Citizen Producer    102            0                102
    2   sole proprietorship  45            0                45
```

i tried coalesce, count or something that can return 0 but it's doesn't work

i need them to return like this

```
    No  Type of Producer    NewProducer   ExistProducer    Total

    1   Citizen Producer    102            0                102
    2   sole proprietorship  45            0                45
    3   SME Producer          0            0                  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Use `PEBPC` as your main table and left join it to `TPDCS`. Note that I move all your WHERE conditions in the JOIN part:

```
SELECT 
    pe.[ID] AS [No]
    ,pe.[NAME] AS [ProducerType]
    ,COALESCE(COUNT(CASE tp.[NewProducer] WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [NewProducers]
    ,COALESCE(COUNT(CASE tp.[NewProducer] WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [ExistProducer]
    ,COALESCE(COUNT(tp.[NewProducer]),0) AS [Total]
FROM [PEBPC] pe
    LEFT  JOIN [TPDCS] tp ON pe.[ID] = tp.[estbProducerID]
    AND tp.[OrganizationAddrProvince] IS NOT NULL
    AND tp.[OrganizationAddrProvince] = '81'
    AND tp.[libDocumentID] IN(SELECT [ParentID] FROM [TPDTS] WHERE [CategoryID] IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY pe.[ID], pe.[NAME]
ORDER BY pe.[ID]
```

Comment: @touchchai euapermchokchai: You can make this query even more readable. 1) You don't need COALESCE, because COUNT is never NULL. 2) You can remove `ELSE NULL`, because this is the default. 3) Remove `AND tp.[OrganizationAddrProvince] IS NOT NULL`. '81' is never NULL. 4) Remove 'WHERE 1 = 1`, because all your criteria is in the ON clause now.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Thank you for your information, it's use and helpful i don't know that before it's hard to make a query more readable